# Regex expression for URL redirection plugin?

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, redirect

I'm looking for the right regex expression to use on a redirection plugin.

Here is our current set up:
[image]

We're looking to make it so that when someone completes a survey they are taken to a thank you page, but when they have only been linked to the page they are redirected to the survey. At first I realized that we couldn't simply have the links between the two pages since the redirect was actually coming from jotforms. I'm not sure what's wrong in my regex expression that won't let it through, though! That said, it worked on a mobile phone.

Additionally, it would be nice to be able to allow any links from our domain. I add  | for or between the rules, right? And how do you make it match anything on the domain?

Thanks for your help!

*edit* I now realize that one issue was that I called it a permanent redirect instead of a temporary redirect which was causing issues with a browser that had already seen the redirect and stored it as permanent.

Comment: You should post the answer even if it was your question. It makes it easier for anyone else who might potentially have this problem

Comment: I still don't have an answer, unfortunately!

Comment: Maybe you need a less strict source URL regex? `/new-subscriber-survey`? Also note that in regex, literal `.` should be escaped: `submit\.jotformpro\.com`.

Comment: Please post your current regex (not a screenshot, please) and some test data that you want matched.

Comment: When posting a regex question, always try to include example strings you're trying to match, and example strings you're looking to exclude. Also post any regex attempts you've made so far. You may be close, but just need tweaking, and they may also hugely benefit from optimisation. Regex can be easy to get working, but is also easy to screw up from a performance standpoint.